# How to turn off distributed's work-stealing programatically

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I ship software that uses distributed to parallelize across processes.

I would like to turn off work-stealing for my users because I have found that it causes some instability because of locks used upstream.

I create Client objects for users both from scheduler files (created via dask-mpi) and from LocalClusters. How can I turn off work-stealing for my users without making them do it themselves during the install process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Config file

You can change the following line in their config.yaml file

```
work-stealing: False     # workers should steal tasks from each other
```

You can also set this by setting the environment variable `DASK_WORK_STEALING` to an empty string as follows:

```
export DASK_WORK_STEALING=
```

#### Programmatically

You can run the following on the scheduler after it has started:

```
scheduler.periodic_callbacks['stealing'].stop()
```

You might consider modifying the dask-mpi executable to do this (search for `scheduler.start` in that code and run this on the next line) or your users might do this themselves with the following code:

```
def f(dask_scheduler):
    dask_scheduler.periodic_callbacks['stealing'].stop()
client.run_on_scheduler(f)
```

Comment: Does this have to happen after running start?

The following does not work:

```

    >>> from distributed import Client
    >>> client = Client()
    >>> def f(dask_scheduler):
    ...   dask_scheduler.periodic_callbacks['stealing'].stop()
    ...
    >>> client.run_on_scheduler(f)
```

Comment: By my understanding that should work fine.  If it doesn't then I recommend constructing a minimum reproducible failing example and include that as part of a bug report at github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new

Comment: I've also added a solution with environment variables, in case that's easier for you.